# Python repeated output from program

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

I created a binary search but I am stuck at a problem. Whenever I run main( ) I just get None for when key equals 8, 5, 2, and 1. I also am trying to have bsearch return the index of the key_point value in integer_list but instead it just returns the key_point. If someone could let me know what is going wrong I would appreciate it.

```
def bsearch(integer_list, key_point, start, end):
    midpoint = (start + end) // 2
    if start >= end:
        return None
    elif integer_list[midpoint] == key_point:
        return key_point
    elif integer_list[midpoint] > key_point:
        return bsearch(integer_list, key_point, start, (midpoint - 1))
    elif integer_list[midpoint] < key_point:
        return bsearch(integer_list, key_point, (midpoint + 1), end)


def main( ):
    integer_list = [x + 1 for x in range(0, 10)]
    key = 11
    p = len(integer_list) - 1
    start = integer_list[0]
    end = integer_list[p]
    while key >= 1:
        bsearch(integer_list, key, start, end)
        print(bsearch(integer_list, key, start, end))
        key = key - 1
```

Comment: I understand that you might be doing algorithm's practice -- but if you _aren't_, python already supplies binary search algorithms in the `bisect` module.

Comment: Why is your start and end equal to the first and last value of the list? It should be first and last index of the array, in this case, 0 and 9

Comment: If you don't want a None return, then don't program it in. if start >= end: return None. Return something else, even if you have to add a previous result temp variable to do it.

Comment: @SamyArous Can you clarify? Sorry I'm confused by that

Comment: It returns the key_point because of this line: `return key_point`. Change that to return something else if you want to return something else.

Comment: @yeezy The principle of binary search is that it takes a start index and end index and search for the sub array defined by that range of position. What you are passing to your function in main is not an index but the value from the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have following errors:

1) The call to `binary_search` from `main` contains `start = 1 and`end =  10`which should have been`start = 0 and `end =  9`(value of the indices).We find all the mid points according to indices.

2) Just check `start > end` because `start == end` is absolutely correct and the cases where you got a `None` were all due to this case. All the cases where you returned due to this condition were actually the case where `integer_list[midpoint] == key_point` holded true.

Here's the corrected code:

```
def bsearch(integer_list, key_point, start, end):
    midpoint = (start + end) // 2
    if start > end:
        return None
    elif integer_list[midpoint] == key_point:
        return key_point
    elif integer_list[midpoint] > key_point:
        return bsearch(integer_list, key_point, start, (midpoint - 1))
    elif integer_list[midpoint] < key_point:
        return bsearch(integer_list, key_point, (midpoint + 1), end)


def main():
    integer_list = [x + 1 for x in range(0, 10)]
    key = 11
    p = len(integer_list) - 1
    start = integer_list[0]
    end = integer_list[p]
    while key >= 1:
        print(bsearch(integer_list, key, 0, p))
        key = key - 1
main()
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: start = integer_list[0] is wrong. It does work for this example because integer_list[0] is equal to 1, but for everyother case, it will fail. Start should always be 0

Comment: @SamyArous Yes, you're right. I'm very sorry for this mistake. Edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up indexes and values several times in your algorithm.
Your base/found case should be returning midpoint since that's the place you found it, but you're returning key_point, the value you're actually searching for instead.

And again, when you're setting up your loop, you're setting your start and end values to be the contents of the List at the beginning and end, instead of the beginning and ending index.  Some of these errors will become more noticeable if for your test_list you use a set of numbers that isn't just sequential numbers 1-11. Right now it just happens to line up.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are passing values to the function instead of indexes:

```
start = 0
end = len(integer_list) - 1
```

Second you need to return None when both start and end are reversed. not when they are equal

```
if start > end:
        return None
```

Third, why would you return the value you are searching for? it does not make any sense. You should return the index of the element instead.

```
elif integer_list[midpoint] == key_point:
        return mid_point
```

Finally, if you want to follow what almost every search method returns, you should return -1 when you can't find the value you are looking for, instead of None. This will save you some headaches.

```
if start > end:
        return -1
```